# How to get width/height of displayed image in javafx imageView?

Tags: image, javafx-2

I need to get width/height of displayed image in imegView and compare it to orginal image size which is in imageView.getImage().getWidth()/getHeight() and listen changes if user resize it form application GUI.

I get this size from `imageView.fitWidthProperty()` and similar for height, but I get size of imageView not image within it:
[image]

I get size of blue which is imageView but I need size of displayed image (green). How can I get it as property to listen when user resize window app (green also change size but it seems to have max and min size so it stop resize with imageView when it is max or min).

I use this property to compute % of size of orginal image in bottom right below blue rectangle.

Is it possible?

E: Below is fxml of this tab:

```
<BorderPane fx:id="root" fx:controller="..."
        xmlns:fx="..." xmlns="..." stylesheets="@...css">
<center>
    <StackPane>
        <ImageView fx:id="..."/>
        <fx:include source="...fxml" fx:id="..."/>
    </StackPane>
</center>
<bottom>
    <VBox fx:id="..." minHeight="110" styleClass="small-padding" spacing="5">
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" spacing="5">
            <fx:include source="...fxml" resources="..."
                        fx:id="..."/>
        </HBox>
        <TextArea fx:id="..." promptText="%..." styleClass="-fx-description-text-area"/>
    </VBox>
</bottom>
```

Answer (score 5):

When the `ImageView` is set to preserve the aspect ratio, one has to calculate the real dimensions by hand. At least I've not found another way.

```
double aspectRatio = image.getWidth() / image.getHeight();
double realWidth = Math.min(imageView.getFitWidth(), imageView.getFitHeight() * aspectRatio);
double realHeight = Math.min(imageView.getFitHeight(), imageView.getFitWidth() / aspectRatio);
```

To explain this a bit: getFitHeight/Width is your blue rectangle. When preserving the aspect ratio of the source image, at least one side of the blue rectangle must have the same length as the corresponding side of the green rectangle. Also, the green rectangle will always be inside of the blue one, hence the call to `Math.min()`.

Answer (score 3):

> ~>1)

The fact that the `Image` is not resizing to cover all the [ImageView](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) has to do with preserveRatio method.If you want to be covered `setPreserveRatio(false);`
with a combination of `setSmooth( true );`

> ~>2)

The green border is the size of the original image.

> ~>3)

Before adding the `Image` to the `ImageView` you can do:

```
Image image = new Image("FILE:...");
image.getWidth( );
image.getHeight( );
```

And that is the original size of the image.

As for the size of the image when it is displayed inside the `ImageView`:

```
imageView.getFitWidth();
imageView.getFitHeight();
```

For the size of `ImageView` inside the Scene (the blue border in your question):

```
imageView.getWidth();
imageView.getHeight();
```

`ImageView` class has properties for the above.

Comment: imageView.getFitWidth() doesn't work. But I found what I needed in imageView.boundsInParentProperty() so problem solved.

Comment: Same here, you need to use: `listView.boundsInParentProperty().get().getWidth()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any property that you could use directly to get at the numbers you want but you might propose this as an improvement for a future version of JavaFX.

What you can do now is write some code which tracks all proerties of the ImageView which have an influence on the size of the displayed image and then compute the displayed size yourself. This does not sound too complicated to me.