# Can not get the right color when hovering over image node in javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx, colors

When I **hover over** the **Image** I am getting the wrong **color** value in some pixels of the image, which seems to be a kind of pixel shift.

I am using a **MouseMoved** event on the **ImageView** to get the x and y **coordinates** of the cursor on the image, then I create a **Color** instance using the color from those coordinates. Finally, I use that color to fill a Circle node.

I would like to know why it is returning the wrong color value for some pixels.

**PS**: I tried that on png and jpeg images but the same thing is happening.

This is the **initialize** method of the controller where I am setting the **event listener** to the **ImageView**:

```
 @FXML
    public ImageView inputImage;

    public void initialize() {

        inputImage.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
            int xPosition = (int) event.getX();
            int yPosition = (int) event.getY();

            Color pixelColor = inputImage.getImage().getPixelReader().getColor(xPosition, yPosition);

            circleColor.setFill(pixelColor);
        });
    }
```

A part of the **FXML** file :

```
            <VBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" alignment="CENTER">
                <HBox alignment="CENTER">
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="50.0"/>
                    </VBox.margin>

                    <ImageView fx:id="inputImage" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" fitHeight="300"
                               fitWidth="300">
                        <Image url="@../Resources/Default-image.png" backgroundLoading="true"/>
                    </ImageView>
                </HBox>

                <HBox alignment="CENTER">
                    <Button onAction="#handleFileChooserClick" text="load image"/>
                </HBox>
            </VBox>

            <VBox prefWidth="200" alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                <padding>
                    <Insets top="60" bottom="60"/>
                </padding>

                <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                    <Circle radius="70" fill="orange" stroke="black" fx:id="circleColor"/>
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="50.0"/>
                    </VBox.margin>
                </VBox>

                <Button textAlignment="CENTER" text="Isolate Color"/>
            </VBox>
```

This how it looks like :
[image]

Comment: I suspect you are using a high-res display or your display scaling is set to something higher than normal 1x.

If you are on Windows 10 try `Override High DPI scaling behavior` to `Application` or `System`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (including the image used) so this behavior can easily be replicated by copy and paste with no change or addition (no fxml is required for that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're explicitly setting the fitwidth / fitheight through fxml so the display resolution may differ from the original image resolution if the image dimensions are not equal to the manually set fit width and height.

what you need to do is convert the mouse position x and y accordingly from the display range of [0...displayWidth] and [0...displayHeight] to the original dimensions [0...originalWidth] [0...originalHeight].

now the tricky part is that when you use preserveRatio, the display dimensions are calculated and are not always equal to the fit width and height, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48049156/8556269) describes a way to get the display width and height of an imageView that uses preserve ratio.

now that you have the display dimensions and the original dimensions, you can calculate a new pair (x, y) :

```
int adjustedX = mouseX * originalWidth / displayWidth;
int adjustedY = mouseY * originalHeight / displayHeight;
```

and you can use those to get the color from the input image.

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce this (OS X 12.5.1, JDK/JavaFX 18.0.2), here is an example, that you can try:

[image: example]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Objects;

public class ColorPickerApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Circle swatch = new Circle(30);

        ImageView imageView =
                new ImageView(
                        new Image(
                                Objects.requireNonNull(
                                        ColorPickerApp.class.getResource(
                                                "Dragon-icon.png"
                                        )
                                ).toExternalForm()
                        )
                );
        imageView.setPickOnBounds(true);

        imageView.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
            int xPosition = (int) event.getX();
            int yPosition = (int) event.getY();

            Color pixelColor = imageView.getImage().getPixelReader().getColor(xPosition, yPosition);
            swatch.setFill(pixelColor);
            System.out.println(pixelColor);
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, swatch, imageView);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));


        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

The dragon image, Dragon-icon.png, in the sample:

[image: Dragon-icon.png]

I set [pickOnBounds](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#pickOnBoundsProperty) to true so that the transparent parts of the image will register as color changes when moused over.

If you move the mouse really rapidly, results may not be exact because the polling of the mouse info isn't immediate, but if you move the mouse slowly, it should work fine, at least from my testing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the FXML I already set the pickOnBounds property to true. For the picture, the problem is not only occurring for that specific image but all the ones I have tried.

Comment: this example worksforme too, on win10 with 150% scaling - does is work for you @Starnec ? If so, there's something wrong in your code. If not, you have to dig further.

Comment: Perfect example.